# concatenating strings

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableArray * oneText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[oneText addObject:[arraySystem objectAtIndex:[countImage intValue]]];
[oneText addObject:@".png"];
NSString *oneTextText=[oneText objectAtIndex:0];
[oneTextText stringByAppendingString:[oneText objectAtIndex:1]];
NSLog(oneTextText);
```

Why can't the above code print 'Lenght.png'? as `[arraySystem objectAtIndex:[countImage intValue]]` is equal to 'Lenght'
it prints only 'Lenght'

Answer (score 4):

put a "oneTextText=" when calling stringByAppendingString, it should be:

```
oneTextText = [oneTextText stringByAppendingString:[oneText objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: This one gets me all the time; You get used to it eventually and the reference docs are your friend! :-D

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply. i thought it only had to return on itself.